# jinja2 in python and rendering

Tags: python, jinja2

I am unable to decipher the error here. Can any one help ?

```
from jinja2 import Template

prefixes  = {
    "10.0.0.0/24" : {
        "description": "Corporate NAS",
        "region": "Europe",
        "site": "Telehouse-West"
    }
}

template = """
Details for 10.0.0.0/24 prefix:
 Description: {{ prefixes['10.0.0.0/24'].description }}
 Region: {{ prefixes['10.0.0.0/24'].region }}
 Site: {{ prefixes['10.0.0.0/24'].site }}
"""

j2 = Template(template)
print(j2.render(prefixes))
```

Error:

```
  File "c:\Users\verma\Documents\Python\jinja\jinja1.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(j2.render(prefixes))
  File "C:\Users\verma\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\verma\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "<template>", line 3, in top-level template code
  File "C:\Users\verma\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 466, in getitem
    return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'prefixes' is undefined
```

I was expecting the jinja2 rendering to work.

Comment: Does changing `{{ prefixes['10.0.0.0/24'].description }}` to `{{ prefixes.10.0.0.0.24.description }}` work? If it does just repeat that naming convention for `Region` and `site`.

Comment: See [Template.render](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Template.render) API docs on howto pass data to render. You pass a dict - the template has access to nontents of the dict, but it is unavare of its name.

Answer (score 2):

`render` uses keyword arguments. replace `print(j2.render(prefixes))` with `print(j2.render(prefixes=prefixes))` and it should work.